# Even an image in data set used to train is giving opposite values when making prediction

Tags: image, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to ML and TensorFlow. I am trying to build a CNN to categorize a good image against corrupted images, similar to rock paper scissor tutorials in tensor flow, except for only two categories.

[The Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/Course%202%20-%20Part%208%20-%20Lesson%202%20-%20Notebook%20(RockPaperScissors).ipynb)

### Model Architecture

```py
train_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAINING_DIR,
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode='categorical'
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VALIDATION_DIR,
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode='categorical'
)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 150x150 with 3 bytes color
    # This is the first convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # The second convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The third convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The fourth convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    # 512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])


model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=25, validation_data = validation_generator, verbose = 1)

model.save("rps.h5")
```

Only Change I made was turning **input shape** to **(150,150,1) to (150,150,3)** and changed last layers output to **2 neurons from 3**. The training gave me consistently accuracy of **90 above** for data set of **600 images** in each class. But when I am making a prediction using code in the tutorial, it gives me highly wrong values even for data in the data set.

### PREDICTION

Original code in TensorFlow tutorial

```py
for file in onlyfiles:
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150,3)) # changed target_size to (150, 150,3)) from (150,150 )
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  images = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
  print(fn)
  print(classes)
```

> I changed target_size to (150, 150,3)) from (150,150) in my belief that since my input is a 3 channel image,

### Result

> It gives very wrong values [0,1][0,1] for even images in which are in dataset

But when I changed the code to this

```py
 for file in onlyfiles:
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150,3))
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  x /= 255.   
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
  print(fn)
  print(classes)
```

> In this case values come like

```
    [[9.9999774e-01 2.2242968e-06]]
    [[9.9999785e-01 2.1864464e-06]]
    [[9.9999785e-01 2.1641024e-06]]
```

one or two errors are there but it is very much correct

So my question even though the last activation is softmax, why it is now coming in decimal values, is there any logical mistake in the way I am making predictions.? I tried binary also, but couldn't find much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note -

1. When you are changing output classes from 2 to 3, you are asking the model to categorise into 3 classes. This would contradict your problem statement which separates good and corrupted ones i.e 2 output classes (a binary problem). I think it can be reversed from 3 to 2 if I have understood the question correctly.
2. Second the output you are getting is perfectly correct, the neural network models outputs probabilities instead of absolute class values like 0 or 1. By probability, it tells how likely it belongs to say class 0 or class 1.
3. Also , as mentioned above by @BBloggsbott - you just have to use np.argmax on the output array which will tell you the probability of belonging to class 1 (Positive class) by default. 
   Hope this helps.
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) returns probability distributions for the vector it gets as input. So, the fact that you are getting decimal values is not a problem. If you want to find the exact class each image belongs to, try using the [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) function on the predictions.